# How to update SWING GUI automatically for any Database changes

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a page (Swing GUI)  where in I am displaying a data according to some condition . When the page loads, the page fetches data from the DB and displays the data in GUI. Now if there is any change in the database , I want the change to be reflected immediately in my GUI without a run/reload/refresh. Any idea how to implement this functionality. I am using JDBC Connection ... Kindly suggest... Note : I do not want a run java code or refresh the page , the data should get updated automatically. Thanks in advance,

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Timer;``
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.*;

import DemoDBConn.MysqlConnection;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GUI extends JFrame
{

Connection connection=null;
    public GUI()
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();       
        JLayeredPane LPane = new JLayeredPane();
        jf.getContentPane() .add(LPane);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/background4.gif"));

        JLabel background = new JLabel();
        background.setIcon(i);
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);

        JLabel flight = new JLabel();
        flight.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/acs_md_dis.png")));
        flight.setBounds(270, 0, 800, 768);

        JLabel seat1 = new JLabel();
        seat1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymAmberInd.png")));
        seat1.setBounds(320, 230, 10, 20);

        JLabel seat2 = new JLabel();
        seat2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymAmberInd.png")));
        seat2.setBounds(370, 230, 10, 20);

        JLabel seat3 = new JLabel();
        seat3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymAmberInd.png")));
        seat3.setBounds(320, 280, 10, 20);

        JLabel seat4 = new JLabel();
        seat4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymAmberInd.png")));
        seat4.setBounds(370, 280, 10, 20);


        LPane.add(background, new Integer(1));
        LPane.add(flight, new Integer(2));
        LPane.add(seat1, new Integer(3));
        LPane.add(seat2, new Integer(3));
        LPane.add(seat3, new Integer(3));
        LPane.add(seat4, new Integer(3));




    try {
        String query ="Select * from passengersdetails";
        connection = MysqlConnection.dbConnector();
        PreparedStatement pst= connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("seateNumber").equals("A1")){
                if(rs.getString("status").equals("OK")){
                    seat1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymGreenInd.png")));
                }
                else if(rs.getString("status").equals("NOT OK")){

                }
                else{

                }
            }
            else if(rs.getString("seateNumber").equals("A2")){

                if(rs.getString("status").equals("OK")){
                    seat2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymGreenInd.png")));
                }
                else if(rs.getString("status").equals("NOT OK")){

                }
                else{

                }
            }
            else if(rs.getString("seateNumber").equals("A3")){
                if(rs.getString("status").equals("OK")){
                    seat3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymGreenInd.png")));
                }
                else if(rs.getString("status").equals("NOT OK")){

                }
                else{

                }
            }
           else if(rs.getString("seateNumber").equals("A4")){
               if(rs.getString("status").equals("OK")){
                    seat4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            GUI.class.getResource("/images/acSymGreenInd.png")));
                }
                else if(rs.getString("status").equals("NOT OK")){

                }
                else{

                }
            }   

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(1024,768);
    jf.setResizable(false);     
    jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GUI gui = new GUI();



    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think JDBC supports this. What you could try, is have some code around the database, on the "server" side. Then use the [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to forward changes to the GUI.

Comment: And how do you plan on making the "server side" behave like the "observable" part of the pattern ?  Or, what does that look like, "having code *around* the database" ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout The code would wrap the database. It will still need to regularly poll the database, unless the DBMS has mechanisms to signal changes to the outside world. In essence, that code works like a Model and the GUI as View.

Comment: Please provide a minimal verifiable code.

Comment: @ErwinSmout what about timer ..?

Comment: "do not want to run a java code" and "do not want to refresh page".  You know the effect of "regularly poll" on the system load ?  As for : "signal changes to the outside world" : none of the SQL vendors knows how to do that (and at any rate as far as I know there's nothing in the JDBC API either that aims to support that kind of stuff).

Comment: "timer" clashes with [what I understood from] "do not want to refresh a page".  Time-triggered repeating of the query is the same thing as refreshing.  And at any rate, the SQL engine is unlikely to keep behaving well once the load starts accumulating.

Comment: @ErwinSmout ,So is there any other way of doing it...??

Comment: I politely suggest you carefully consider the deeper meaning of the first two words of my answer.

Comment: Though Swing is less relevant to this than the DB related tags added instead, I'll offer one tip before opting out. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Thanks for all above response, Now I am able to do this by using  java timer.

Answer (score 2):

Stop dreaming.

DBMS engines exist to answer questions (queries) in a one-question-one-answer kind of way.  Question answered ?  Job done.  That's how it works.  They do not exist to keep track of which user has asked which question and wants to be notified whenever the given answer to the question is impacted by whatever other update to the database is done by whoever else.

In fact, if your query is a full-blown relational expression involving various operators of the relational algebra, there does not even exist any engine that would know how to compute that stuff [efficiently enough for the whole machine to not immediately come to a grinding halt over all the computation needed].